# PCIe Bus Error: sevetity=Corrected. Kali Linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux

[image: фото сообщения]
До этого работал, теперь не запускается.
При запуске просто спамит это сообщение. Я ничего не трогал, оно само.

Comment: https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/linux-hardware/12585679 вайфайка глючит

Comment: Я не могу его даже запустить. Как переустановить его с загрузочной флешки? Уже устанавливал заново, но проблема не решалась.